# How to find what is using physical memory in a Java process

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory, jstat

I have a Java program which has `Xms` and `Xmx` set as 2GB and 8GB respectively. The top shows the process is using `VIRT` of 27GB and `RSS` of 14GB.

**Questions:**
  1. How did this process consume double the physical memory than `Xmx`?
  2. visualvm shows that process is using 1.5Gb of Heap memory. Then where is the rest 13Gb of physical memory?
  3. How do I find, who/what is consuming the memory?

**jstat gc**

```
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
4608.0 8192.0 4608.0  0.0   815616.0 267717.8 1398272.0  1316095.0    �      �      6418  133.309   8      6.176  139.486
```

**jstat gccapacity**

```
NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC      PGCMN    PGCMX     PGC       PC     YGC    FGC 
698880.0 2796032.0 1270784.0 4608.0 8192.0 815616.0  1398272.0  5592576.0  1398272.0  1398272.0        �        �        �        �   6418     8
```

**jstat gcutil**

```
S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
100.00   0.00  32.82  94.12      �   6418  133.309     8    6.176  139.486
```

This is the pmap output of this process (filtered)

```
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
0000000001385000    8740    8740    8740 rw---   [ anon ]
00000005c0000000 1398272 1398272 1398272 rw---   [ anon ]
0000000615580000 4194304       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
0000000715580000 1270784 1270784 1270784 rw---   [ anon ]
0000000762e80000 1525248       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00000007c0000000    2304    2244    2244 rw---   [ anon ]
00000007c0240000 1046272       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaab0000000   65536   48148   48148 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaab4000000   24320   23664   23664 rwx--   [ anon ]
00002aaab57c0000  221440       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaac3000000   16384    3028    3028 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaac404e000   65224       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaac8000000    8192    8184    8184 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaac8800000   15420    5108    5108 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaacc021000   65404       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaad0000000    3332    3332    3332 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaad0341000   62204       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaad4000000   65484   47684   47684 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaad7ff3000      52       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaad8000000     320     320     320 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaad8050000   65216       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaadc000000  262144   48240   48240 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaaec032000   65336       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaaf0032000   65336       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaafc067000   65124       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab00000000   54596   42060   42060 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab03551000   10940       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab04000000   65136   54248   54248 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab08000000   10520   10508   10508 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab08a46000   55016       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab0c021000   65404       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab10021000   65404       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab14021000   65404       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab18000000   42988   15088   15088 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab1a9fb000   22548       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab1c000000    7452    3648    3648 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab1c747000   58084       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab20079000   65052       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab24000000   22368   15264   15264 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab255d8000   43168       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab28021000   65404       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab2c000000   65528   63288   63288 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab30000000   65500   45408   45408 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab34000000   54180   54180   54180 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab374e9000   11356       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab38000000   65488   45804   45804 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab3c000000   49404   49404   49404 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab3f03f000   16132       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab40000000    9796    9796    9796 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab40991000   55740       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab44000000   65520   28436   28436 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab48000000   65492   45340   45340 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab4c000000    9448    9448    9448 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab4c93a000   56088       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab50000000    8528    8528    8528 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab50854000   57008       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab54000000    9184    9184    9184 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab548f8000   56352       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aab5c000000   65528   39388   39388 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab60000000   65508   61896   61896 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab64000000   65516   35344   35344 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab6c000000   65480   38284   38284 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab70000000   65480   37100   37100 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab74000000   65488   63328   63328 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab78000000   65516   37656   37656 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab7c000000   65504   37108   37108 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab80000000   65480   36608   36608 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab84000000   65516   36856   36856 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab88000000   65508   38692   38692 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab8c000000   65528   63124   63124 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab90000000   65492   62684   62684 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab94000000   65524   38176   38176 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab98000000   63152    2876    2876 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aab9c000000   65476   38232   38232 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaba0000000   65508   63648   63648 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaba4000000   65496   37980   37980 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaba7ff6000      40       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaba8000000   65476   37208   37208 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aababff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabac000000   65416   64072   64072 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabaffe2000     120       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabb0000000   65488   38488   38488 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabb3ff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabb4000000   65532   39624   39624 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabb7fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabb8000000   65528   38080   38080 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabbbffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabbc000000   65492   34564   34564 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabbfff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabc0000000   65528   64452   64452 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabc3ffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabc4000000   65532   36080   36080 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabc7fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabc8000000   65516   63488   63488 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabcbffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aabcc000000   65524   35620   35620 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabd0000000  131056  128324  128324 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabd8000000   65532   63848   63848 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabdc000000   65524   63712   63712 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabe0000000   65524   38632   38632 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabe4000000   65492   37504   37504 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabe8000000   65512   38668   38668 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabec000000   65524   63216   63216 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabf0000000   65480   38520   38520 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabf4000000   65524   63744   63744 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabf8000000   65484   39676   39676 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aabfc000000   65492   41752   41752 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac00000000   65520   63704   63704 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac04000000   65532   39356   39356 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac08000000    5476    4236    4236 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac08559000   60060       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac0c000000   65484   39260   39260 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac10000000   65476   34736   34736 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac14000000   65512   63776   63776 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac18000000   65504   37972   37972 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac1c000000   65476   63536   63536 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac20000000   65512   37420   37420 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac24000000   65532   63896   63896 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac28000000   65528   63592   63592 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac2c000000   65508   63900   63900 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac30000000   65512   64464   64464 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac34000000   65516   38812   38812 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac37ffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac38000000   65484   63244   63244 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac3bff3000      52       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac3c000000   65484   64448   64448 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac3fff3000      52       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac40000000   11248    7776    7776 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac40afc000   54288       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac44000000   65532   63136   63136 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac47fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac48000000   65536   39324   39324 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac4c000000   65532   63512   63512 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac4ffff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac50000000   65532   64128   64128 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac53fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac54000000   65492   37176   37176 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac57ff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac58000000   65488   63384   63384 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac5bff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac5c000000   65516   38044   38044 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac5fffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac60000000   65528   63568   63568 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac63ffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac64000000   65488   63664   63664 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac67ff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac68000000   65512   37400   37400 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac6bffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac6c000000   65512   63636   63636 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac6fffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac70000000   65492   63296   63296 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac73ff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac74000000   65496   63060   63060 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac77ff6000      40       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac78000000   65504   37592   37592 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac7bff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac7c000000   65488   63396   63396 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac7fff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac80000000   65512   63544   63544 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac83ffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac84000000   65476   63428   63428 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac87ff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac88000000   65528   36584   36584 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac8bffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac8c000000   65528   62440   62440 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac8fffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac90000000   65524   61740   61740 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac93ffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac94000000   65504   38300   38300 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac97ff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac98000000   65532   63304   63304 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac9bfff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aac9c000000   65524   62980   62980 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aac9fffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaca0000000   65484   62572   62572 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaca3ff3000      52       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaca4000000   65504   36380   36380 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaca7ff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaca8000000   65524   63124   63124 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacabffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacac000000   65504   61712   61712 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacafff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacb0000000   65512   39124   39124 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacb3ffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacb4000000   65480   62428   62428 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacb7ff2000      56       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacb8000000   65524   61740   61740 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacbbffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacbc000000   65536   60972   60972 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacc0000000   65536   39148   39148 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacc4000000   65476   61812   61812 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacc7ff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacc8000000   65492   60732   60732 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaccbff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaccc000000   65508   61152   61152 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaccfff9000      28       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacd0000000   65520   37016   37016 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacd3ffc000      16       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacd4000000   65480   60848   60848 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacd7ff2000      56       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacd8000000   65496   59156   59156 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacdbff6000      40       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacdc000000   65512   52632   52632 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacdfffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aace0000000   65532   61316   61316 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aace3fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aace4000000   65484   61548   61548 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aace7ff3000      52       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aace8000000   65496   59620   59620 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacebff6000      40       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacec000000   65532   61300   61300 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaceffff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacf0000000   65492   59532   59532 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacf3ff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacf4000000   65484   58916   58916 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacf7ff3000      52       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacf8000000   65512   59472   59472 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacfbffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aacfc000000   65488   60424   60424 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aacffff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad00000000   65532   59456   59456 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad03fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad04000000   65476   59316   59316 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad07ff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad08000000   65496   59304   59304 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad0bff6000      40       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad0c000000   65520   60156   60156 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad0fffc000      16       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad10000000   65504   59124   59124 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad13ff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad14000000   34232    1712    1712 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad1616e000   31304       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad18000000   65504   60568   60568 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad1bff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad1c000000   65512   60736   60736 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad1fffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad20000000   65532   58472   58472 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad23fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad24000000   65500   44804   44804 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad27ff7000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad28003000    1016      24      24 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad28101000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad28104000    1016      24      24 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad28303000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad28306000    1016      24      24 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad28404000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad28407000    1016      24      24 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad28808000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad2c000000   65484   41552   41552 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad2fff3000      52       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad30000000   65476   34456   34456 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad33ff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad34000000  131068   61120   61120 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad3bfff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad3c000000   65476   33152   33152 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad3fff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad40000000   65516   29996   29996 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad43ffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad44000000   65476   28600   28600 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad47ff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad48000000   65516   28880   28880 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad4bffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad4c000000   65520   27936   27936 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad4fffc000      16       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad50000000   65516   27360   27360 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad53ffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad54000000   65492   26232   26232 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad57ff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad58000000   65504   27076   27076 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad5bff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad5c000000   65532   29764   29764 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad5ffff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad60000000   65488   30732   30732 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad63ff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad64000000   65496   29664   29664 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad67ff6000      40       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad68000000   65524   37624   37624 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad6bffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad6c000000   65520   30568   30568 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad6fffc000      16       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad70000000   65532   29000   29000 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad73fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad74000000   65492   28296   28296 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad77ff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad78000000   65532   29516   29516 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad7bfff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad7c000000   65480   30340   30340 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad7fff2000      56       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad80000000   65508   30288   30288 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad83ff9000      28       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad84000000   65504   28696   28696 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad87ff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad88000000    7812    7812    7812 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad887a1000   57724       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad8c000000   65492   30864   30864 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad8fff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad90000000   65508   31260   31260 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad93ff9000      28       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad94000000   65504   30100   30100 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad97ff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad98000000   65524   30416   30416 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad9bffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aad9c000000   65492   30128   30128 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aad9fff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aada0000000   65528   47828   47828 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aada3ffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aada4000000   65532   60364   60364 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aada7fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aada8000000   65476   58236   58236 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadabff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadac000000   65532   63240   63240 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadaffff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadb0000000   65492   63296   63296 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadb3ff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadb4000000   65516   63132   63132 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadb7ffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadb8000000   65432   63312   63312 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadbbfe6000     104       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadbc000000   65508   62696   62696 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadbfff9000      28       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadc0000000   65512   59356   59356 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadc3ffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadc4000000   65500   63268   63268 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadc7ff7000      36       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadc8000000   65524   63576   63576 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadcbffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadcc000000   65500   63504   63504 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadcfff7000      36       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadd0000000   65492   63832   63832 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadd3ff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadd4000000  131024  127824  127824 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaddbff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aaddc000000   65488   63092   63092 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaddfff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aade0000000   65528   60576   60576 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aade3ffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aade4000000   65512   63728   63728 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aade7ffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aade8000000   65508   62896   62896 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadebff9000      28       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadec000000   65524   62568   62568 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadefffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadf0000000   65532   63964   63964 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadf3fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadf4000000   65520   63356   63356 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadf7ffc000      16       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadf8000000   65524   64512   64512 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadfbffd000      12       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aadfc000000   65512   64100   64100 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aadffffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae00000000   65528   59212   59212 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae03ffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae04000000   65504   63608   63608 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae07ff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae08000000   65484   63788   63788 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae0bff3000      52       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae0c000000   65492   63484   63484 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae0fff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae10000000   65508   62612   62612 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae13ff9000      28       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae14000000   65512   63580   63580 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae17ffa000      24       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae18000000   65520   63440   63440 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae1bffc000      16       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae1c000000   65508   63224   63224 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae1fff9000      28       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae20000000   65488   60692   60692 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae23ff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae24000000   65496   63532   63532 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae27ff6000      40       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae28000000   65424   62592   62592 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae2bfe4000     112       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae2c000000   65488   57628   57628 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae2fff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae30000000   65504   58240   58240 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae33ff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae34000000  131064  112876  112876 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae3bffe000       8       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae3c000000  131028   99960   99960 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae43ff5000      44       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae44000000  131036  107564  107564 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae4bff7000      36       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae4c000000   65516   61068   61068 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae4fffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae50000000   65532   60248   60248 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae53fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae54000000   64580   61180   61180 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae57f11000     956       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae58000000   65520   62560   62560 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae5bffc000      16       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae5c000000   65476   62948   62948 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae5fff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae60000000   65532   62636   62636 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae63fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae64000000   65516   58204   58204 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae67ffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae68000000   65476   62432   62432 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae6bff1000      60       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae6c000000   65480   58284   58284 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae6fff2000      56       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae70000000   65532   62064   62064 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae73fff000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae74000000  131040  123668  123668 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae7bff8000      32       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae7c000000   65496   56732   56732 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae7fff6000      40       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae80000000   65488   61856   61856 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae83ff4000      48       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae84000000   65516   61920   61920 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae87ffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae88000000   65500   61072   61072 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae8bff7000      36       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae8c000000  130984  123132  123132 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae93fea000      88       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00002aae94000000  131012  112060  112060 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae9c000000   65496   60976   60976 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaea0000000   65520   55920   55920 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaea4000000   65516   61072   61072 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaea8000000  131020  111164  111164 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaeb0000000   65492   59932   59932 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaeb4000000   65488   56976   56976 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaeb8000000   65500   52592   52592 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaebc000000   65496   60960   60960 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaec0000000   65520   60648   60648 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaec4000000   65484   59532   59532 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaec8000000  131056  112376  112376 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaed0000000   65480   58600   58600 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaed4000000   65524   52532   52532 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaed8000000   65532   52068   52068 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaedc000000   65524   44964   44964 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaee0000000   65524   54216   54216 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aaee4000000   65492   50796   50796 rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffced813000     132      32      32 rw---   [ stack ]
---------------- ------- ------- ------- 
total kB         27113012 14991740 14983652
```

Comment: Gb = Giga-bit I assume you mean GB which means Giga-Byte.

Comment: Xmx is the  maximum heap size, this can be a fraction of all the memory regions the JVM uses.

Comment: When you have pairs of memory regions, one large and one small, there are often thread stacks.  However most of the regions look like native memory blocks. I would look for use of direct memory. Are you using any JNI libraries?

Comment: Java NIO with native ByteBuffers will be allocated off-heap, this could be the source of the additional memory usage.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, the pmap output had one small and one large memory blocks. I removed the small memory blocks to fit the question character restriction. I am not using any JNI libraries.

Comment: @cppcoder By pairs I mean e.g. `00002aaba7ff6000` with no permissions and immediately after it `00002aaba8000000` these have often been a thread stacks. I think the first region is an unusable protected virtual memory region to avoid overrun of a previous region or popping of the stack beyond the start.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you meant this right? `00002aae64000000   65516   58204   58204 rw---   [ anon ]
00002aae67ffb000      20       0       0 -----   [ anon ]` There are lot of such pairs. I have removed the small blocks of those pairs in the pmap output given in question. Does that mean there is some issue with the threads? How do I find the root cause of memory overusage?

Comment: @cppcoder I mean the `-----` before the `rw---` actually but close. I would look at how many threads you are creating. use `jstack {pid}` do you need them all?

Comment: Other anon regions are usually native memory or direct memory accesses. Some libraries use these. e.g. networking libraries.

Comment: `jstack` is listing 51 threads in total out of which 14 are my threads/Runnable (executor service) and the rest and from the libraries I use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138563/discussion-between-cppcoder-and-peter-lawrey).